# Something about multithreads with singleton

Tags: java, multithreading

I used a singleton to read configuration:

```
Class Property {
      private String username;
      private String password;
      private static Property props;

      public String getUsername() {
          return username;
      }
      public String getPassword() {
          return password;
      }

      public static Property getInstance() {
          if(props == null) {
          synchronized(Property.class) {                
                   props = new Property();
                   props.initial();
              } 
          }
          return props;
      }

      public void initial() {
          Properties prop = new Properties();
          prop.load(new FileInputStream(new File("application.properties")));
          username = prop.getProperty("username");
          password = prop.getProperty("password");
      }
}
```

Then, in the first thread, I got an instance of Property, like `props = Property.getInstance`

I called the method `getUsername()` and `getPassword()` like this:

`props.getUsername()`/`props.getPassword()`.

However, these two methods **return null**. And in the second thread and the threads after, I can get username and password from these two methods.

I don't know why this is happening. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be prop instead of props in the last two lines?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's prop.

Answer (score 4):

Change your static `props` to `prop` at `initial()` method

```
public void initial() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(new FileInputStream(new File("application.properties")));
    username = prop.getProperty("username");
    password = prop.getProperty("password");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Props" are no longer null after new `Property()` has been executed. So `props` may be returned even if the `initial()`-method was not fully executed.

Please try the following code:

```
public static Property getInstance() {
      synchronized(Property.class) {                
      if(props == null) {
               props = new Property();
               props.initial();
          } 
      }
      return props;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but what's the difference? And why could props be returned before `initial()` was not fully executed? Shouldn't `initial()` be executed first and then `return` happens?

Comment: We don't care about the return. As soon as the Property object is constructed, it's assigned to the props static member variable. Any other threads are able to read from the static variable props, regardless of whether the call of the initial thread to getInstance has returned or not.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that props.getProperty in the code above is a typo while posting the question.

Before the synchronized statement you check props == null.  It's possible that props has been created (new Property), so not null, but the call to initial has not completed yet. So, the object returned by getInstance is not properly initialized yet before calling getUsername/password. The simplest solution would be to make the whole method synchronized but that might be a performance issue.

Also, with the current implementation, you might end up creating two instances of the singleton. E.g. if props == null and eventually both threads make it into the synchronized block. You should check if props is null in the synchronized section as well to avoid creating two instances (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)

Probably the more elegant way to handle multi-threaded singletons is the Initialization on demand idiom (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom).

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I don't quite understand what you said:"So, the object returned by getInstance is not properly initialized yet before calling getUsername/password". Do you mean `return props` happens before the method initial() is fully executed?

Comment: Here is the scenario I have in mind: Assume there are two threads (A and B). Thread A calls getInstance first, props is null, so it creates the singleton instance (props) and then calls the initial method to set the username and the password. However, between the call to the constructor and the initial() method, thread B calls getInstance too. Props is not null anymore so it returns the instance created by thread A. Then thread B calls getUsername, but thread A might still be reading the properties file in order to set username. Hence, username is not set and thread B gets null instead.

Answer (score 0):

What both antonis_wrx and Andy N. are saying is that your synchronization is not "wide" enough:

```
1: if(props == null) {
2:     synchronized(Property.class) {                
3:         props = new Property();
4:         props.initial();
5:     } 
6: }
```

Think of 2 threads executing in parallel. Thread A executes line 1 and `props == null` returns true. Right after this, the OS switches to Thread B. Thread B also executes the same line 1 and the check still returns true (props is still null). Now both threads will continue and execute the synchronized block.

So say Thread A acquires the monitor on Property.class first (line 2) and initializes the props (lines 2-5). Now Thread B is free to also acquire the monitor in line 2 - it executes line 3 and at this very moment, Thread C calls `getInstance().getUsername()`.

Thread C's `getInstance` executes line 1 which returns false and then returns `props` (which was just constructed by Thread B to `new Property()`). Calling `getUsername()` on this un-initialized Property object gives you the null you are seeing.

Note that for this example, Thread C might as well be the same Thread A (I just wanted to make it easier to read).

You can solve the problem with what has already been suggested (synchronizing the whole `getInstance` method). An alternative approach is to have a static block which does the initialization for you like this:

```
Class Property {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private static Property props;

    static {
        props = new Property();
        props.initial();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your patience and explaining this. It helps.